# How can I replace ' ' values with null values in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, replace

EDIT/UPDATE: I finally found a solution - the following worked:

```
df=df.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True)
```

I am trying to replace ' ' values with null values in python. Essentially, I am converting an text file to Python using substrings. In the file, all rows have the same number of characters but only one column - I need to convert this to distinct columns each with row values - example below:

```
df['column1'] = df['data'].str[0:2]
df['column2'] = df['data'].str[5:14]
```

In cases where a column's row value should be null, it is instead a space or a series of spaces (' '). I have tried the following:

```
df=df.replace(' ', "Null")
df=df.replace(' ', None)
df=df.replace('', None)
df=df.replace(r'\s*', None, regex=True)
```

This has not worked for me (it doesn't even change cases when the entire cell value is ' '); the space values remain, both for cells with spaces in between numbers (like ' 1' rather than '1') and for cells which should be empty. How can I solve this?

Example of data is below. Where there appears to be a blank value, it is actually one or two spaces (depending on the number of spaces of the cell):\

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example of `df`? (`df.to_dict('list')`)

Comment: What do you mean "converting an ASCII file to Python" ?? A variable can be None in python which is essentially Null in other languages. But "Null" doesn't exist. Also what do you mean by "cell value"?

Comment: From the [`replace` documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html): "str: string exactly matching to_replace will be replaced with value".  Meaning it only replaces whole strings, not parts of a string.

Comment: When you use `df.replace(r'\s*', None, regex=True)`... Do you assign the output (the returned value) anywhere? By default (unless you also provide `inplace = True`) Pandas will do the changes in a copy of the input dataframe (`df`). Have you tried `df = df.replace(r'\s*', None, regex=True)` ?

Comment: @BorrajaX just tried that and it didn't change anything unfortunately

Comment: Don't put the answer in the question, make an actual answer.

Comment: I'm curious, why is np.nan an improvement over a string with blanks?  Your question was not very clear.

Answer (score 0):

You should maybe use an empty string, not space:

```
df.replace('', None)
```

If you're unsure, you can go for:

```
df.replace(r'\s*', None, regex=True)
```

Or, to restrict to full matches:

```
df.replace(r'^\s*$', None, regex=True)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, none of these worked for me :(

Comment: @eades can you please provide a reproducible input?

Comment: I have created an example file; I don't think I can upload it though, I'm looking into how I can provide this to you

Comment: Can't your provide a dictionary? `df.to_dict('list')`, if really you need a file, maybe [wetransfer](https://wetransfer.com/)?

Comment: The file has 35 columns and hundreds of thousands of rows. When I use df.to_dict('list') it is way too long and incomprehensible.

I've added a picture of the file in excel... not sure what else I can do!

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`strip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) to remove both leading and trailing spaces.

```
df['column1'] = df['data'].str[0:2]
df['column1'] = df['column1'].str.strip()
df['column2'] = df['data'].str[5:14]
df['column2'] = df['column2'].str.strip()
```